# Bootstrap datepicker format date differently on display than on value

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datetime, datepicker, formatting

I want to use Twitter Bootstrap's datepicker. I want the actual input to DISPLAY in the format mm/dd/yyyy but the value of the object I want it to create/pass should be in yyyy-mm-dd. I am aware of this property:

```
"data-date-format" => "mm-dd-yyyy"
```

But that changes both the way the date is displayed and how the value is formatted. I also have this in my JS:

```
$(this).datepicker({
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true,
  pickTime: false
});
```

I'm not really sure what the format part is doing, but changing it doesn't change the value that is created by the input.

Comment: I would like to see this feature too, I want to display the date in local UK format (dd/mm/yyyy) but it needs to be parsed as yyyy-mm-dd due to a piece of software I'm using. 

Also I think "data-date-format" and "format" are the same thing just one is attached via HTML and the other via JS.

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47466659/1153909

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a solution from bootstrap for this problem.

as said on the [docs](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html#format)

you can set format as an object with 2 parsing functions: toValue and toDisplay.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
format: {
    /*
     * Say our UI should display a week ahead,
     * but textbox should store the actual date.
     * This is useful if we need UI to select local dates,
     * but store in UTC
     */
    toDisplay: function (date, format, language) {
        var d = new Date(date);
        d.setDate(d.getDate() - 7);
        return d.toISOString();
    },
    toValue: function (date, format, language) {
        var d = new Date(date);
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
        return new Date(d);
    }
  },
   autoclose: true 
});
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution. Thank you.

Comment: This does not solve the original issue at all: the displayed date is still the one posted on form submit. This only allows you to define the string-to-date and date-to-string conversion functions so the input field may be manually edited consistently with the calendar view.

Comment: @ZeRemz well it seems to work for me and for the OP, so weird.

Answer (score 6):

When I am faced with such a problem, where I want data displayed differently than I want it communicated, I usually write a short script to copy the value into a hidden element where I maintain the 'correctly'-formatted data which the user does not see.

This is the best solution I can offer at the moment, as I do not know of any way to convince the Bootstrap Datepicker to use two formats simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

here is example script to copy the value into a hidden element to maintain yyyy-mm-dd format :

```
    $('.datepicker').on('changeDate', function(e){
        var date = e.date;
        var day = ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
        var month = ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        console.log(year + '-' + month + '-' + day);
        $(this).next('input[type=hidden]').val(year + '-' + month + '-' + day);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use the default date pickers in Chrome, FF, Edge, and Safari.  In particular, I wanted the scrolling behavior on the phone.

I set the input type to "date" and pass in the value as yyyy-mm-dd.  This works great on Chrome, FF, Edge, and Safari.  Automatically gets formatted as mm/dd/yyyy except in Safari, which shows longer format.

IE doesn't support the "date" type.  So, when I pass the data into the "date" textbox, it needs to be converted manually to mm/dd/yyyy format and then I use the bootstrap datepicker.

So I test for IE.  Then, if it is, do the transformation in the val()

```
     // Format the values to be mm/dd/yyyy
     ElementsJQ.val(function (index, value) {
          
          // Check for a date value
          let testDate = new Date(value);
          if (isNaN(testDate.getMonth())) {
               $(this).attr('value', '');
                return '';
           }

           // Parse the value to get its parts
           let dateParts_ = value.split('-');
           if (dateParts_.length != 3) {
               $(this).attr('value', '');
               return '';
           }

           // Create formatted date
           let formattedDate = dateParts_[1] + '/' + dateParts_[2] + '/' + dateParts_[0];

           // Test - real date?
           testDate = new Date(formattedDate);
           if (isNaN(testDate.getMonth())) {
               $(this).attr('value', '');
               return '';
           }

           $(this).attr('value', formattedDate);
           return formattedDate;
            });

            // Apply bootstrap date picker.
            ElementsJQ.datepicker();

        }
```