# How to convert JS date string into django datetime format?

Tags: javascript, python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap datepicker and on date selection, I make an ajax call and send in the user selected date, I want to change the date of the object in the database, but I get this error from Django:

```
[u"'04/23/2018' value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]
```

How do I convert it to the specified format? This is my code:

Template:

```
$('#project_date').on('changeDate',function()
{
$.ajax({
    url: btn.attr("data-url"),
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        new_date: $('#project_date_input').val()
    },
    success: function(data){
        //do something
    }
```

views.py

```
def project_change_date(request, pk):
    data = dict()
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=pk)

    project.end_date = request.GET.get('new_date')
    opp.save()
```

Comment: I think your datepicker is sending only date whereas your database field is datetime. You have to format the coming format to your db format

Comment: Yes, I got that, but I cannot ask the user to provide the time in this scenario, hence we can set the time to `00:00:00`, but I want to how I can convert '04/23/2018' to `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap datepicker format date differently on display than on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021207/bootstrap-datepicker-format-date-differently-on-display-than-on-value)

Comment: @KoshVery It is not a duplicate, I am not talking about how to display the date in a particular format on my template, I have already acheived that, what I am asking is how to convert a string object into a pythoh/django datetime object. The question was answered by ArpitSolanki

Comment: @DeA, my point is you do not need to convert date on the server as the datepicker can store date value in one format (e.g. `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`) and display date in another (e.g. `MM/DD/YYYY`). So your question is in fact the same, imho. But if you prefer to pollute your code with unnecessary operations... Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a third party library like [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil)

```
In [14]: from dateutil.parser import parse

In [15]: c = "04/23/2018"

In [16]: parse(c)
Out[16]: datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 23, 0, 0)

In [17]: print(parse(c))
2018-04-23 00:00:00 # this format is same as your db's datetime format
```

Comment: Did not know about the amazing package! Worked like magic! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime

project.end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.GET.get('new_date'), '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```